# Apache deny ONLY DIRECT access to a htm file

Tags: javascript, apache, permissions

Is possible disable DIRECT access to a htm file in a folder but let the same file be readable if index.htm call him?

Example, this is my website
index.htm
htm (folder) with page_1.htm inside.

I would like denay access if somebody type:
http://www.nomesito.com/htm/page_1.htm
directly in the address bar.

But i would like to let index.htm load the content of htm/page_1.htm via javascript.

Is that possible?

I read a similar post in this forum,

Comment: is your website written in php? java?

Comment: just htm e javascript, there is a similar question in this forum but the guy was using php. Not my case.

Comment: without a server side proofing of rights and user informations this is not possible. You need a server side script like php to check such stuff.